# Why psql 9.2.4 on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I go to my proj folder and type: `rails db` in terminal and I have this

```
rails db
psql (9.3.1, server 9.2.4)
Type "help" for help.

employeelist_development=#
```

why it shows that server version of pg is 9.2.4 ?
is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes that is normal. It is not coming from rails. `9.3.1` is the `psql` version and `9.2.4` is the `postgresql` version.

Comment: I thought that psql is shortened from postgresql. So it's not?

Comment: `psql` is the command like `pg_dump`. `postgresl` is the database.